# aprox 25000 lines of html making IE6 and IE8 not respond

Tags: html, performance, internet-explorer

So the application I am working on is used by users working on IE6 and IE8
this recent functionality we have developed caused 1 page to be as heavy as 1.92 mb
we have done the following.

1. Moved the JS on the .cshtml files to JS files
2. cleaned up all the unneccessary hidden fields
3. optimized the loops in js.

What more can I do to make the rendering faster?

Comment: Why is the page so "heavy"?

Comment: we have over 160 odd services and each service can have over 15 controls for each service.

Comment: find a different way of using 160 services, 4 pages of 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all your users need all services at every time? Look into only loading the bare essentials at the start and loading the services on-demand when the user needs one, using Ajax-based controls. That way, you offload part of your page loading to when the user needs it, instead of all the time.